# Date of registration on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to find out date of registration profile on Facebook? Is it possible? Can i do it from API? 
I google it, but can't find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no public way to get this information. Sorry.