# Facebook application - time spend at FB

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm developing FB app. And I dont know how to count overall time spend at facebook. any ideas? Is there something like registration time at facebook? I was looking for this but didn't find anything.

Thank you for your answer and help!

Comment: You would like to track how much time a user has spent on any part of Facebook, not just your application? If yes, then you are out of luck, you can't that (unless you write a browser extension).

Comment: I just want count date from registration to now.

Comment: I think, Facebook won't give that information..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi as far as i know it is not possible and it was confirmed by a a facebook engineer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902259/date-of-registration-on-facebook). Sorry

Comment: I don't want to hear this :( anyway thank you!

Comment: @Yanko: just so you know, if a question duplicates an existing question, it is best to just close as a dup. I've done that now with your link, thanks.